# Loop through array element one at at a time, perform some proccessing, repeat until end

Tags: php, arrays

This is my `$part_array`:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => 1015789 
  [1] => 1029402 
  [2] => 1031345 
  [3] => 1036476 
  [4] => 1061512 
  [5] => 1065031 
  [6] => 1069892 
  [7] => 1070721
  [8] => 1073222 
  [9] => 1074811
) 

$next_index = $next_index + 1;
$next_part = ($part_array[$next_index]);
```

Retrieve part# information using MySQL

Display part# and related information on page. Click on button to display next part# and related information and repeat until end, or user exits.

Each time I increment the `$next_index` and get the $next_part, the `$part_array` has the next part # added to the end of the array, so if I have read 3 records, my array now looks like this:

```
Array ( 
[0] => 1015789 
[1] => 1029402 
[2] => 1031345 
[3] => 1036476 
[4] => 1061512 
[5] => 1065031 
[6] => 1069892 
[7] => 1070721 
[8] => 1073222 
[9] => 1074811
[10] => 1015789 
[11] => 1029402 
[12] => 1031345
)
```

How else could I do this without adding to the array? Does anyone have any suggestions? I am new to PHP and would greatly appreciate any advice.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do, but generally speaking, one uses a `foreach` loop to cycle through an array.  http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Sounds like a homework problem that could be solved by paying attention in class.